# Python Nested List: How to print specific elements and append to each sublist

Tags: python, nested-lists

```
quizes = [["Andrew"], ["Amy"], ["Jared"], ["Bob"], ["Sarah"]]

for i in range(len(quizes)):
    grade = eval(input("Enter", quizes[i][0],"grade:"))
    quizes[i].append(grade)
    print(quizes[i])
```

Hey guys so I been working on this for the past week and can't solve this. I am trying to get my program to ask "Enter [person1] grade: " and so on and append a second element to each sublist which will be their grade and then print the contents of the entire list. Any help is appreciated

Comment: One big problem is you are using `input` like `print`. `print` allows you to provide a variable number of arguments, but `input` will not. `"Enter " +  str(quizes[i][0]) + " grade:"` will solve the error you see.

Comment: This looks right, except that you didn't print the whole list at the end.  Dod you mean to add `print(quizes)` after the loop?  And did you know the plural of `quiz` is `quizzes`? ;)

Comment: @TimRoberts And the use of `input` was incorrect.

Comment: Can you explain why this code isn't working the way you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is input takes 1 string as a parameter, you are passing 3 instead. So:

```
quizes = [["Andrew"], ["Amy"], ["Jared"], ["Bob"], ["Sarah"]]

for l in quizes:
    grade = eval(input(f"Enter {l[0]} grade:"))
    l.append(grade)
    print(l)
```

However, I respectfully don't understand the point of using `eval` here. [Eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) turns data into code. Using eval on user input creates a great security hole. In the above code, what if the user input `quizes.clear()`? The whole array will be emptied. What if he inputs something eviler?

Consider (assumes valid grades only contain numbers):

```
quizes = [["Andrew"], ["Amy"], ["Jared"], ["Bob"], ["Sarah"]]

for l in quizes:
    while True:
        try:
            grade = float(input(f"Enter {l[0]} grade:"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please input a number.")
        else:
            l.append(grade)
            break
print(quizes)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. What is the container you used input(f"{1[0]}") called and where can I read about that?

Comment: It's f-string, please read here: 
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals
Also:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```py
    grade = eval(input("Enter", quizes[i][0],"grade:"))
```

to

```py
    grade = eval(input("Enter " + quizes[i][0] + " grade:"))
```

`input` does not behave as `print` does.  You can't use commas to join text in any other function (except for a *very small* number of custom functions and modules), and you should stay away from them at if that's confusing for you to only use them sometimes.

With that change, does your code work now?  You didn't tell us why it wasn't working the way you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that `input()` accepts only one argument as the input prompt, unlike `print` which can take any number of arguments - you're giving 3 parameters to the input function - `"Enter"`, `quizes[i][0]`, and `"grade:"`.

You can try concatenating them - like `input("Enter "+str(quizes[i][0])+" grade:")` (the `str()` conversion is not needed if you know that all the *quizes[i][0]* will be strings already),
or even use string formatting - `"Enter {} grade".format(quizes[i][0])` or `f"Enter {quizes[i][0]} grade:"`

This should be enough, but there are 2 more changes you can make to your code if you like -

- Iterate over the nested lists directly (`for sub_list in quizes:`)
- Using `int()` or `float()` to convert a returned input string containing a number will also work in place of `eval`

For example

```py
for quiz in quizes:
   grade = eval(input("Enter {} grade:".format(quiz[0])))
   quiz.append(grade)
   print(quiz)
```

EDIT: [Python docs on string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) The `f"..."` syntax works only for Python 3.6+

Answer (score -1):

Now that I'm looking at it, what did yours do wrong?

```
quizes = [["Andrew"], ["Amy"], ["Jared"], ["Bob"], ["Sarah"]]

for quiz in quizes:
    grade = eval(input("Enter " + quiz[0] + " grade:"))
    quiz.append(grade)
    print(quiz)

print(quizes)
```

Comment: It used `input` as if it were `print`.